# ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN in batches but with NEWSEQUENTIALID()

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a large table, but not huge (less than 2 million rows on aging hardware), and when adding a non-nullable column to an existing table, I usually follow the structure set out [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/188410/45757) to avoid problems with the script timing out when our database migrations run on deployment (FYI - This isn't a full text index problem).

So, in summary, I:

- Alter the table and add the column as NULL and do not add a default constraint
- Backfill the column in batches
- Alter the table and change the column to be NOT NULL and add the default constraint

However, in the following case I want to add a new UNIQUEIDENTIFER column and fill it with NEWSEQUENTIALID() rather than NEWID() values.

Without running in batches, my script would look like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Invoice' 
    AND COLUMN_NAME = 'InternalId')
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE Invoice 
        ADD InternalId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT [DF_Invoice_InternalId] DEFAULT (NEWSEQUENTIALID())
END
GO
```

However if I split this up into batches, and attempt to fill the nullable InternalId with the following:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Invoice' 
    AND COLUMN_NAME = 'InternalId')
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE Invoice 
        ADD InternalId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL
END

DECLARE @MaxId INT, @LoopStart INT, @LoopEnd INT, @LoopSize INT = 50000
SELECT @MaxId = MAX(InvoiceId) FROM Invoice
SELECT @LoopStart = MIN(InvoiceId) FROM Invoice
SET @LoopEnd = @LoopStart + @LoopSize

PRINT 'Updating InternalIds to a new GUID'
WHILE @LoopStart <= @MaxId
BEGIN
    -- update internal id
    UPDATE I 
    SET InternalId = NEWSEQUENTIALID()
    FROM Invoice I
    WHERE I.InvoiceId BETWEEN @LoopStart AND @LoopEnd

    SET @LoopStart = @LoopEnd + 1
    SET @LoopEnd = @LoopEnd + @LoopSize
END

IF EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Invoice' 
    AND COLUMN_NAME = 'InternalId' 
    AND IS_NULLABLE = 'YES')
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE Invoice 
        ALTER COLUMN InternalId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
END

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM sys.objects WHERE name = 'DF_Invoice_InternalId')
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE Invoice
        ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Invoice_InternalId]  
        DEFAULT ((NEWSEQUENTIALID())) FOR [InternalId]
END
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 302, Level 16, State 0, Line 40 The newsequentialid() built-in
> function can only be used in a DEFAULT expression for a column of type
> 'uniqueidentifier' in a CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE statement. It
> cannot be combined with other operators to form a complex scalar
> expression.

Any tips on how to work around this? Or am I over-thinking this?

The reason for doing this change is to expose the Sequential IDs (`InternalId` or could be called `PublicId`) externally in an API, as a replacement for the current sequential numeric Ids (InvoiceId). The numeric Id (the primary key) should have been kept internal, as it exposes a sequential and guessable internal value. The Sequential GUID is still sequential, but also not so easily guessable. To illustrate the point, I'm doing something like this, but @First is being provided via an API call. It is used for polling and processing new invoices using a watermarking process.

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    DateCreated DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT(GETDATE()),
    Code NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)

DECLARE @Id INT
DECLARE @NO_OF_CHARS INT = 10
SET @Id = 1

WHILE @Id <= 12000
BEGIN 
    
   INSERT INTO #Test (Code) VALUES (SUBSTRING (REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(40), NEWID()), '-',''), 1, @NO_OF_CHARS))
   SET @Id = @Id + 1
END

ALTER TABLE #Test 
    ADD InternalId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL DEFAULT(NEWSEQUENTIALID())

DECLARE @First UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
SELECT * FROM #Test
SELECT @First = InternalId FROM #Test WHERE Id = 1
SELECT * FROM #Test WHERE InternalID > @First

DROP TABLE #Test
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add the column as nullable with the constraint and then update the column with DEFAULT value. Conceptually something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE Invoice 
    ADD InternalId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL 
    CONSTRAINT [DF_Invoice_InternalId] DEFAULT (NEWSEQUENTIALID())

UPDATE I 
SET InternalId = DEFAULT
FROM Invoice I

 ALTER TABLE Invoice 
        ALTER COLUMN InternalId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
```

But based on your motivation I would advice against using NEWSEQUENTIALID. It IS guessable. If someone gets one of the generated IDs he can easilly guess former and following values. Take a look at this StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24158535/2603086)

> In most cases, the next newsequentialid can be predicted by taking the
> current value and adding one to the first hex pair.
>
> In other words:
>
> 1E29E599-45F1-E311-80CA-00155D008B1C
>
> is followed by
>
> 1F29E599-45F1-E311-80CA-00155D008B1C
>
> is followed by
>
> 2029E599-45F1-E311-80CA-00155D008B1C

Comment: I guess the alternative is to use NEWID, but then when the API call comes in, I look up the numeric Id with a simple db call, and then use that for the greater than query. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A colleague pointed out how you can use the DEFAULT keyword in this instance, although I'm not 100% sure how it works, it works.

Using the example from above, the following shows how this works:

```
-- create the example table
CREATE TABLE #Test (
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    DateCreated DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT(GETDATE()),
    Code NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)

DECLARE @Id INT
DECLARE @NO_OF_CHARS INT = 10
SET @Id = 1

WHILE @Id <= 12000
BEGIN 
    
   INSERT INTO #Test (Code) VALUES (SUBSTRING (REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(40), NEWID()), '-',''), 1, @NO_OF_CHARS))
   SET @Id = @Id + 1
END

-- add the new column with a default but it is still nullable
ALTER TABLE #Test 
    ADD InternalId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL DEFAULT(NEWSEQUENTIALID())
GO

DECLARE @MaxId INT, @LoopStart INT, @LoopEnd INT, @LoopSize INT = 50000
SELECT @MaxId = MAX(Id) FROM #Test
SELECT @LoopStart = MIN(Id) FROM #Test
SET @LoopEnd = @LoopStart + @LoopSize

PRINT 'Updating InternalIds to a new GUID'
WHILE @LoopStart <= @MaxId
BEGIN
    -- update internal id using the DEFAULT
    -- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72604/adding-non-nullable-newsequentialid-column-to-existing-table
    UPDATE #Test 
    SET InternalId = DEFAULT
    WHERE Id BETWEEN @LoopStart AND @LoopEnd

    SET @LoopStart = @LoopEnd + 1
    SET @LoopEnd = @LoopEnd + @LoopSize
END

-- now make this not null
ALTER TABLE #Test ALTER COLUMN InternalId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL

-- do a basic test
DECLARE @First UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
SELECT * FROM #Test
SELECT @First = InternalId FROM #Test WHERE Id = 1
SELECT * FROM #Test WHERE InternalId > @First

DROP TABLE #Test
```

Alternatively, this SQL Fiddle shows it in action:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2735a1/36)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    DateCreated DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT(GETDATE()),
    Code NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)
```

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE @Id INT
DECLARE @NO_OF_CHARS INT = 10
SET @Id = 1

WHILE @Id <= 10
BEGIN   
   INSERT INTO Test (Code) VALUES (SUBSTRING (REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(40), NEWID()), '-',''), 1, @NO_OF_CHARS))
   SET @Id = @Id + 1
END

-- add the new column with a default but it is still nullable
ALTER TABLE Test 
    ADD InternalId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL DEFAULT(NEWSEQUENTIALID())
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2735a1/36/0)**:

**Query 2**:

```
DECLARE @MaxId INT, @LoopStart INT, @LoopEnd INT, @LoopSize INT = 50000
SELECT @MaxId = MAX(Id) FROM Test
SELECT @LoopStart = MIN(Id) FROM Test
SET @LoopEnd = @LoopStart + @LoopSize

PRINT 'Updating InternalIds to a new GUID'
WHILE @LoopStart <= @MaxId
BEGIN
    -- update internal id using the DEFAULT
    -- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72604/adding-non-nullable-newsequentialid-column-to-existing-table
    UPDATE Test 
    SET InternalId = DEFAULT
    WHERE Id BETWEEN @LoopStart AND @LoopEnd

    SET @LoopStart = @LoopEnd + 1
    SET @LoopEnd = @LoopEnd + @LoopSize
END

-- now make this not null
ALTER TABLE Test ALTER COLUMN InternalId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2735a1/36/1)**:

**Query 3**:

```
-- do a basic test
SELECT * FROM Test
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2735a1/36/2)**:

```
|  Id |              DateCreated |       Code |                           InternalId |
|-----|--------------------------|------------|--------------------------------------|
| 191 | 2022-01-28T13:59:08.947Z | D61874FEB6 | BFC0423E-F36B-1410-80BF-800000000000 |
| 192 | 2022-01-28T13:59:08.947Z | C596780C9F | C0C0423E-F36B-1410-80C0-800000000000 |
| 193 | 2022-01-28T13:59:08.947Z | 3356A26232 | C1C0423E-F36B-1410-80C1-800000000000 |
| 194 | 2022-01-28T13:59:08.947Z | D6D509EDE7 | C2C0423E-F36B-1410-80C2-800000000000 |
| 195 | 2022-01-28T13:59:08.947Z | E956CBCF4B | C3C0423E-F36B-1410-80C3-800000000000 |
| 196 | 2022-01-28T13:59:08.947Z | E32EAB6E92 | C4C0423E-F36B-1410-80C4-800000000000 |
| 197 | 2022-01-28T13:59:08.947Z | B2137001AA | C5C0423E-F36B-1410-80C5-800000000000 |
| 198 | 2022-01-28T13:59:08.947Z | 0FB26856C9 | C6C0423E-F36B-1410-80C6-800000000000 |
| 199 | 2022-01-28T13:59:08.947Z | 5DFCD86CAC | C7C0423E-F36B-1410-80C7-800000000000 |
| 200 | 2022-01-28T13:59:08.947Z | C4BFCCDC59 | C8C0423E-F36B-1410-80C8-800000000000 |
```

**Query 4**:

```
-- test the watermark
DECLARE @First UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = (SELECT TOP 1 InternalId FROM Test ORDER BY Id ASC)
--SELECT 'Watermark is: ' AS [Note], @First AS [WatermarkId]
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE InternalId > @First
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2735a1/36/3)**:

```
|  Id |              DateCreated |       Code |                           InternalId |
|-----|--------------------------|------------|--------------------------------------|
| 192 | 2022-01-28T13:59:08.947Z | C596780C9F | C0C0423E-F36B-1410-80C0-800000000000 |
| 193 | 2022-01-28T13:59:08.947Z | 3356A26232 | C1C0423E-F36B-1410-80C1-800000000000 |
| 194 | 2022-01-28T13:59:08.947Z | D6D509EDE7 | C2C0423E-F36B-1410-80C2-800000000000 |
| 195 | 2022-01-28T13:59:08.947Z | E956CBCF4B | C3C0423E-F36B-1410-80C3-800000000000 |
| 196 | 2022-01-28T13:59:08.947Z | E32EAB6E92 | C4C0423E-F36B-1410-80C4-800000000000 |
| 197 | 2022-01-28T13:59:08.947Z | B2137001AA | C5C0423E-F36B-1410-80C5-800000000000 |
| 198 | 2022-01-28T13:59:08.947Z | 0FB26856C9 | C6C0423E-F36B-1410-80C6-800000000000 |
| 199 | 2022-01-28T13:59:08.947Z | 5DFCD86CAC | C7C0423E-F36B-1410-80C7-800000000000 |
| 200 | 2022-01-28T13:59:08.947Z | C4BFCCDC59 | C8C0423E-F36B-1410-80C8-800000000000 |
```

The "watermark" value being `'BFC0423E-F36B-1410-80BF-800000000000'`

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that NEWSEQUENTIALID cannot guarantee 100% sequential GUIDs for the life of the table's existence. NEWSEQUENTIALID may start back at a lower value after each server reboot. Please review the [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newsequentialid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on this. If that's going to be an issue, you may want to re-evaluate its use for the initial update.

As I understand it, NEWSEQUENTIALID's main purpose is to reduce pain when using a GUID as a clustered key, so as to avoid random inserts all across your data pages and page splits